# jpeg2000 file structure viewer

Tags: jpeg2000

For an application we are developing it is important for us to know how much data (in bytes) is stored in a JPEG2000 code stream for each resolution and quality layer. Does anybody know an application / library that can easily reveal this information?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the free JP2 Metadata Editor:

http://j2k-codec.com/mde.html

It doesn't show you data by resolution but at least it shows you the compressed codestream size for each tile. Maybe it will be helpful to you.

Comment: A nice tool, but unfortunately it does not give me the information I want

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [jpylyzer](http://packages.qa.debian.org/j/jpylyzer.html) and/or [pirl](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/pirl.html) (jp2info) in those cases.